# Can't launch minicom correctly: "Parameter port is private, but is marked public in global config file"

Tags: linux, fedora, minicom

Im not sure if I have this setup right,
I get the following error

Can't launch minicom correctly: "Parameter port is private, but is marked public in global config file"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out,

You have to edit the serial port configuration by typing

**minicom -s**

then scroll down to serial port setup